# SQL: Select Vegetarians

Tags: sql

i'm stuck with a small problem here and i can't seem to find the right answer.

I have a DB with multiple Tables, in which i have ANIMALS and their FOOD. I have to select which ANIMALS only eat VEGETARIAN meals. The table is set up with a BOOLEAN. 0 = MEAT 1 = VEGETARIAN.

There are ANIMALS in the Table who eat MEAT and VEGETARIAN. I don't need them, i strictly need Animals who only eat VEGETARIAN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest using 2 columns, one for MEAT and one for VEGETARIAN.

Comment: How are the two tables connected? Can you provided some sample data/

Comment: Please share your table definitions and some sample data

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what is You table schema, so i will create simple one with fields AnimalId int , Meat bit .

In table the records are stored as simple as that

```
+----------+------+
| AnimalId | meat |
+----------+------+
|        1 |    0 |
|        1 |    1 |
|        2 |    0 |
|        3 |    1 |
|        4 |    0 |
+----------+------+
```

So Animal 1 is eating both meat and vegetables, animal nr 2 only vegetables, animal nr 3 only meat. Our expected result is to get only Animal ID 2 and 4.

You need to group data by AnimalId, take MAX from meat bit column after casting it to int and filter data having 0 as result of MAX.

```
SELECT        AnimalId
FROM            dbo.Animals
GROUP BY AnimalId
HAVING        (MAX(CAST(Meat AS INT)) = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (but it's only mok, since you didn't write anything else):

```
SELECT * 
FROM ANIMALS A
INNER JOIN BR_ANIMALS_FOOD B ON A.ID = B.ID_ANI
INNER JOIN FOODS C ON B.ID_FOODS = C.ID 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FOODS D WHERE B.ID_FOODS = D.ID AND D.FOOD_TYPE = 0) 
 AND C.FOOD_TYPE = 1
```